# How to Split String in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, string, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005-express

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express (not mysql).

I have a string

```
str = 'E1 ; abc ; E2 ; def';
```

I want to split string `str` with respect to delimiter `;` and then insert values into table as follows:

```
Name       Value
E1          abc
E2          def
```

Please help, thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Do you have to use tsql or can you use a programming language like VB, which has a split function?

Comment: @PaulDraper - This is slightly different as the delimiter is delimiting both rows and columns within a row rather than just rows.

Comment: I suppose the end result is different. The essential part (which is common) is splitting the string.